# How to see what nodes are selected with d.selected ? D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I make an array of all the selected nodes ? ie d.selected ?

I have a force layout graph and want to sort out just the selected nodes and hide the unselected.

Is there a way to loop through all the selected nodes, add them to an array and so I can sort them accordingly.

For example. Every node has a name applied to it and all names beginning with A,B and C. I have a function which sorts out all the nodes into a customised layout (names starting with A on one line, B the next and C the next) but that works for every node, not just the selected.

What I wish to happen is to sort just the selected nodes out and hide the unselected

```
peopleArray = [];
peopleIndex = [];

for(i = 0; i < people.data.nodes.length;i++)
    {       
        if(!peopleArray[people.data.nodes[i].name]) 
        {
            peopleArray[people.data.nodes[i].name]=1; 
            peopleIndex.push(people.data.nodes[i].name);
        }
        else{
            ++peopleArray[people.data.nodes[i].name];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could for example apply a CSS class to the selected elements that makes them visible while everything else has a class that makes them invisible.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I already have the ability to hide the selected/unselected. What I have done already is sort the positions of the nodes myself (updated question). But what I wish to happen is just apply this sorting to selected nodes. So what I done previously was add every node to two arrays - one with the name and another with a count, so they spread out appropriately along both axis. How do I do this for selected nodes ? I.e loop through the selected nodes like I did with every node ?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. You can just `.sort()` the selection, can't you?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff updated the question. Here I have sorted every single node into two arrays, 'people' and count of that 'people'. Now I can sort the positioning off all the nodes in the array(i.e every single node) but I want this to work just for the selected nodes.

Comment: So you want the data bound to the selection? `.data()`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff sorted :) appreciate the help, pointed me in the right direction. I would chose your answer as the correct one if it wasnt in the comments. What i basically did was : var selectedData = d3.selectAll(".selectedNode").data(); then go through all that data ;) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data bound to a selection by calling `.data()` without any arguments, i.e.

```
var selected = d3.selectAll(".selectedNode").data();
```